# Making two buttons as on/off and control if dropdownlists should be active or not

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a **on/off** button with two buttons. Both are set inline.

When button1 "Return" is active/On a lightblue color will show. If you click on the other button, this one goes into the lightblue mode and the other stays white.

Have tried to create a jsfiddle so you can see what i got.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixeldk/gn6k1zm7/)

**Code**

```
<div class="bookingbox">
        <form>
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="return-btn">RETURN</button>
                    <button type="button" class="oneway-btn">ONE WAY</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="OutwardLabel">label1</label>
                    <select id="Dropdown">
                        <option>Country</option>
                        <option>Country</option>
                        <option>Country</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ReturnLabel">label2</label>
                    <select id="Dropdown">
                        <option>Country</option>
                        <option>Country</option>
                        <option>Country</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

My problem is that i can't seem to make them active where the color stays... it only shows when i click with the mouse. If i release the mouse again, it's back to white.

The point is when you activate the "one way" button, the last dropdownbox should be disabled.. I'm thinking that javascript can do it.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pure Javascript.
2. Once you click One Way button, it disables the second select.
3. Works by changing the classes of the buttons, based on your CSS.
4. **Edit**: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn6k1zm7/20/)

```js
document.getElementById("return").addEventListener("click", toggleClick, false);
document.getElementById("oneway").addEventListener("click", toggleClick, false);

function toggleClick() {

  if (this.id == "return") {
    this.className = "clicked-return";
    document.getElementById("oneway").className = "unclicked-oneway";
    document.getElementById('dropdown-last').disabled = false;
  } else {
    this.className = "clicked-oneway";
    document.getElementById("return").className = "unclicked-return";
    document.getElementById('dropdown-last').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.bookingbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.unclicked-return {
  width: 49%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: none;
  color: black;
}
.unclicked-oneway {
  width: 49%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: none;
  color: black;
}
.clicked-return {
  width: 49%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #85BCE9;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
}
.clicked-oneway {
  width: 49%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #85BCE9;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookingbox">
  <form>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="return" class="unclicked-return">RETURN</button>
        <button type="button" id="oneway" class="unclicked-oneway">ONE WAY</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OutwardLabel">label1</label>
        <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown-first">
          <option>Country</option>
          <option>Country</option>
          <option>Country</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ReturnLabel">label2</label>
        <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown-last">
          <option>Country</option>
          <option>Country</option>
          <option>Country</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have tried your solution, and so far it looks great.. Is there something i can do to make the return button active at startup? right now when i'm starting the website both are white untill i click ofc.

Comment: Just add `document.getElementById("return").click();` after the `addEventListeners` - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn6k1zm7/22/)

Answer (score 0):

Create two new css classes that will set the color of the button so that it stays that color after clicking. Add two event handlers for the button clicks, adding the 'hide the dropdown' to the one way button.

html:

```
<button type="button" id="return-btn" class="nonactive">RETURN</button>
<button type="button" id="oneway-btn" class="nonactive">ONE WAY</button>
```

css:

```
.active {
    background-color: #85BCE9;
}
.nonactive {
    background-color: white;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

javascript:

```
var btnReturn = document.querySelector('#return-btn'),
    btnOneWay = document.querySelector('#oneway-btn'),
    dropdown = document.querySelector('#Dropdown').parentNode;
btnReturn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btnReturn.className = 'active';
    btnOneWay.className = 'nonactive';
});
btnOneWay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btnOneWay.className = 'active';
    btnReturn.className = 'nonactive';
    dropdown.className = 'form-group hidden';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/gn6k1zm7/7/

```
$('.return-btn, .oneway-btn').on('click', function (){
    $('.active-btn').removeClass( 'active-btn' ).val( '' );
    $(this).addClass( 'active-btn' ).val( 'selected' );
});
```

Is this what you mean? Please note two things:

1. I've included JQuery to achieve this
2. Once you click on a button now, it will set the value attribute to "selected", just in-case you would like to do anything with the buttons on later hand.

Answer (score 0):

This a JS only solution, you just need to attach this function to the onclick event of the two buttons:

```
var returnBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("return-btn")[0];
var oneway = document.getElementsByClassName("oneway-btn")[0];

switchButtons = function switchButtons(clicked) {
    clicked.className = clicked.className + " active-btn";
    if (clicked === returnBtn) {
        oneway.className = oneway.className.replace("active-btn", "");
    } else if (clicked === oneway) {
        returnBtn.className = returnBtn.className.replace("active-btn", "");
    }
}
```

And in the CSS I replaced the following:

```
.return-btn:active {
    background-color:#85BCE9;    
    color: white;
}
.oneway-btn:active {
    background-color:#85BCE9;    
    color: white;
}
```

With the following class:

```
.active-btn {
    background-color:#85BCE9;    
    color: white;
}
```

And on each button click add this class to the clicked button and remove it from the other one.

```js
var returnBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("return-btn")[0];
var oneway = document.getElementsByClassName("oneway-btn")[0];

switchButtons = function switchButtons(clicked) {
    clicked.className = clicked.className + " active-btn";
    if (clicked === returnBtn) {
        oneway.className = oneway.className.replace("active-btn", "");
    } else if (clicked === oneway) {
        returnBtn.className = returnBtn.className.replace("active-btn", "");
    }
}
```

```css
.bookingbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.return-btn {
    width: 49%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: none;
}
.oneway-btn {
    width: 49%;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: none;
}
.active-btn {
    background-color:#85BCE9;
    color: white;
}
#Dropdown {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookingbox">
    <form>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button onclick="switchButtons(this)" type="button" class="return-btn">RETURN</button>
                <button onclick="switchButtons(this)" type="button" class="oneway-btn">ONE WAY</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="OutwardLabel">label1</label>
                <select id="Dropdown">
                    <option>Country</option>
                    <option>Country</option>
                    <option>Country</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ReturnLabel">label2</label>
                <select id="Dropdown">
                    <option>Country</option>
                    <option>Country</option>
                    <option>Country</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is **[the updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/gn6k1zm7/21/)**.